# sql query causing error 2950

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros

This SQL query was generated by Microsoft Access 2003, and works fine when run, but fails when trying to run from a Macro. Is there any obvious error within the query, or any reason it would not work?

```
SELECT tblAuction.article_no, tblAuction.article_name, tblAuction.subtitle, tblAuction.current_bid, tblAuction.start_price, tblAuction.bid_count, tblAuction.quant_total, tblAuction.quant_sold, tblAuction.start, tblAuction.ends, tblAuction.origin_end, tblUser.user_name, tblAuction.best_bidder_id, tblAuction.finished, tblAuction.watch, tblAuction.buyitnow_price, tblAuction.pic_url, tblAuction.private_auction, tblAuction.auction_type, tblAuction.insert_date, tblAuction.update_date, tblAuction.cat_1_id, tblAuction.cat_2_id, tblAuction.article_desc, tblAuction.countrycode, tblAuction.location, tblAuction.condition, tblAuction.revised, tblAuction.paypal_accept, tblAuction.pre_terminated, tblAuction.shipping_to, tblAuction.fee_insertion, tblAuction.fee_final, tblAuction.fee_listing, tblAuction.pic_xxl, tblAuction.pic_diashow, tblAuction.pic_count, tblAuction.item_site_id
FROM tblUser INNER JOIN tblAuction ON tblUser.id = tblAuction.seller_id;
```

Comment: What about your previous statement: if I change it to just tblAuction which is the table and not a query, I get this error: 800a0005': Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: Also VBScript is not generally referred to as a macro, if you mean this to continue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314245/vbscript-to-export-an-access-query-to-a-tab-delimited-file-not-working

Comment: No this is a separate question, nothing to do with vbscript. If I try and run a TransferText macro in Access from this query it will fail, but the query will run. The reason the vbscript fails is because of this query..that is what the problem is narrowed down to.

Comment: Can you post the following: 1) The commands and properties for the Macro. 2) The definition of the tblUser and tblAuction tables.

Comment: What OS is this running on? XP, Vista, or something earlier?

Comment: It is running on XP, and it is Access 2003.
@Patrick, where would I find these things to paste?

Comment: Try lowering the macro security level first. You can use the Access Database documentation tool to create a report of all the object definitions, then copy/paste from there.

Comment: The Macro security level is on the lowest, and the documentation tool made a pdf that was 76 pages long. It might be easier to upload the db somewhere, as it has nothing confidential in it and is only 7mb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean from a Access Macro or from VBScript or from VBA? If you have a macro that is invoking an action then my recommendation would be to convert it to a VBA statement. I assume when you say it works fine when run you mean run as an Access query. You don't specify whether the database is local or is a remote one (i.e. SQL Server). Assuming it is local then running that SQL statement from VBA must work.

Comment: The database is a local access mdb file. I meant running it from a macro returns error 2950,and you are correct that when I said running it fine I meant as an access query. The problem is with the query, as it is preventing both the macro and a vbscript from working

Comment: Where are you executing your "macro" from? Within Access? I'm not finding any details on what err 2950 would be. Can you provide the error text for that?

Comment: The error text is invalid query clause, I have narrowed the problem down to one column, the date in which must be causing a problem

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931407) is for Access 2007, but perhaps you're experiencing this as well.

What's the security level you're using in Access? (Open an MDB, then go to Tools\Macro\Security...). Try lowering the security level and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you were using key words like INSERT and UPDATE as parts of you field names. Such words might be analysed as SQL instructions when sent through a macro, leading to a bug.

Can you try to put them between [brackets]? Anyway it would be better to change the fields names.

Comment: I can try this, however if it works in vbscript would it not work in a macro?

Comment: I imagine there is a piece of code somewhere supposed to parce the text in the macro in order to send it on the Server. Imagine there is a flaw in that piece of code, where strings like "INSERT" and "UPDATE" will be treated as SQL keywords ...